# Request spec works as expected; Controller spec allows :post when it shouldn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, rspec2, controllers

Why is it that this request spec works as it should:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe "POST on a GET route" do
  it "should not allow this" do
    post "/applicants/new"
    assert_response :missing
  end
end
```

But in this controller spec, GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE all work the same when they should not:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ApplicantsController do
  it "should not allow this" do
    post :new
    should respond_with :missing # but it responds with 200
  end
end
```

UPDATE: Added ApplicantsController code and route definition:

```
class ApplicantsController < InheritedResources::Base    
  respond_to :html
  actions :index, :new, :create

  def new
    if current_user
      redirect_to resume_application_path and return
    end

    @applicant = Applicant.new
    @applicant.applications.build
    @applicant.build_user_detail
    new!
  end    
end
```

Routes:

```
resources :applicants
```

**UPDATE**: After much researching and digging into the API, I believe this is by design as the Controller specs inherit from ActionController::TestCase while the Request specs inherit from ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest. In the case of Controller specs, the HTTP verbs become merely descriptive.

Could someone confirm that this is by design? Or should I file a bug report?

Thank you!

Comment: What's in `ApplicantsController`?

Comment: Where do you set `current_user` in specs? Why do you expect `404` response if it should be redirect `301-2`? Where do you spec that the logged in user can access `new` action?

Comment: current_user is a method. It only redirects if current_user returns true, meaning the visitor is logged in. All visitors have access to :new.

Comment: Do you have the view `app/views/applicants/new.html.erb`?

Comment: Yes. All that works fine. The issue is that the Controller spec should be rejecting POST requests for :new, only allowing GET requests; but this only works in the Request spec.

Comment: Title of the question says "allows :get when it shouldn't", in prev comment you said that all users have access to site. Which one is correct?

Comment: Gah! Thanks for pointing that out, Dmytrii. I meant to put :post. They all have access. The Controller spec is allowing :post when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems surprising, but it makes sense when you look at it from the perspective of testing the controller actions in isolation. Normally, controller actions don't need to know about HTTP request methods. Specifying a route without a method illustrates this:

```
  match 'sample' => 'applicants#index'
```

Now `GET /sample` and `POST /sample` will both route to the index action. Unless you code for it, the controller will not know the difference between a GET and a POST request. Controller specs do not test whether request method/action combinations are routable, since that is the responsibility of the routing engine.

You can verify which routes work and which don't with routing specs:

```
it "recognizes and generates #new" do
  { :get => "/applicants/new" }.should route_to(:controller => "applicants", 
      :action => "new")
end

it "does not recognize POST /applicants/new" do
  { :post => "/applicants/new" }.should_not be_routable
end
```

Comment: I almost filed a bug report as the Rails guide mentions specific verbs. I'll see if I can get the documentation or guide updated to reflect this difference. Thank you, zetetic!